# PHP quebrar itens da lista "<li>" em variáveis para adicionar na tabela MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Tenho um formulário com `<textarea>` com o seguinte valor:

```
<textarea id="lista-ingredientes" name="lista-ingredientes">
 <ul>
  <li>sal</li>
  <li>pimenta</li>
 </ul>
<textarea>
```

Preciso que ao enviar o formulário, o PHP "quebre" os itens do `<li>` em variáveis separadas para adicionar uma linha de cada item, o que tenho é esse, mas ele insere tudo em uma linha só:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO receitas_ingredientes (id, ingrediente) VALUES ('NULL', ".$_POST['lista-ingredientes'].")";
```

Acredito que seja algo usando explode e foreach, mas não tenho muito conhecimento e não consegui montar

Comment: Pergunta: por quê você possui um `ul/li` dentro de uma `textarea`? O único tipo permitido de conteúdo para um `textarea` é texto, então esse `ul` seria interpretado como texto puro, não HTML, não fazendo muito sentido.

Comment: sim, é que depois esse valor será puxado da tabela para mostrar dentro de uma div, há uma forma melhor, ou mais correta, de fazer isso?

Comment: o que acontece é que tenho um input ingrediente +botão adicionar que com um jquery vai adicionando todos os ingredientes no text area, para depois inserir todos de uma vez na tabela

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo o ideal é salvar no banco sem os li e quando você puxar do banco e for inserir na visão, adicionar os texto dentro do li em um foreach, por exemplo

Comment: entendi, só pra vc ver, é isso que eu tava fazendo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245268/bot%C3%A3o-adicionar-inserir-valor-do-input-dentro-do-pr%C3%B3prio-formul%C3%A1rio/245274#245274

Comment: o ideal é eu salvar como <textarea>1;2;3;4</textarea> aí quando for mostrar esse valor eu quebro eles e jogo o <li>, isso?

Comment: Não.  Esse `textarea` nem faz sentido existir. Você pode armazenar a lista de ingredientes dentro de uma estrutura do JS ou mesmo estruturar a lista com HTML, de forma correta.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, vc esta colocando no textarea para ir exibindo para o usuário, mas pode colocar tbm em um <input type="hidden" name="lista_ingredientes[]"> salvando como um array e pegar esse campo quando salvar e com isso ficaria melhor para vc trabalhar com os dados

Comment: putz verdade, acabaram me ajudando bastante no outro problema....rs, brigadão!!!!

Comment: Respondi na [pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245268/botão-adicionar-inserir-valor-do-input-dentro-do-próprio-formulário) uma solução muito mais viável para o problema. A que havia sido apresentado lá, e utilizada aqui, não é boa.

Answer (score -2):

você poderia fazer a listagem separando apenas com vírgulas, é bem mais fácil na hora de preencher o textarea pro usuario e mais fácil pra vc fazer um explode com trim. Também pode solicitar ao usuário apenas uma quebra de linha entre os itens, e da mesma forma da vírgula o explode funciona:

```
ex1: " sal, pimenta, tompero, ..."
    $lista = explode(',',$_POST['texto']);

  ex2:
  sal
  pimenta
  tompero


$lista = explode('\n',$_POST['texto']);
```

Comment: Deixei meu -1 porque, no meu entender, isso seria fazer uma *gambiarra* das boas. A solução de armazenar a lista de ingredientes em um *textarea* já é ruim.